# Search engine randomly switch back to MYSQL

Tags: php, elasticsearch, magento, magento2

I have an issue with Elasticsuite and I really cant figure out what's happening !

(https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite)

Sometimes when editing products/category or others action in the admin the search engine is automatically switch back to MYSQL and so the site crash on category pages + search ...

The weird thing is when it happens it look like the indexer are removed from the table "mview_state" ...
Also when it happens the page "Index managment" in the admin is empty.

The only solution to get it back is to flush the cache (sometimes 2 times) and magically it came back

**Magento Version :** 2.3.3 CE

**ElasticSuite Version :**~2.8.0

**Environment :** Production

Error I could catch into exception.log :

```
main.CRITICAL: elasticsuite_categories_fulltext view does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): elasticsuite_categories_fulltext view does not exist. at /var/www/vhosts/****/htdocs/releases/20210211121420/vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View.php:182)"} []
```

[image]

And after flushing cache its back :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated ! Thanks !